# Getting client IP from SignalR Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I am aware this question has been asked before. But in the ~8 years since, SignalR has changed rather a lot.

So does anyone know how to get the IP of a client from the SignalR hub?

I am using SignalR to communicate between two .net core applications on different servers, so there is no HTTP request or serving a website or anything like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your hub you can read `IHttpConnectionFeature` features like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
...
var feature = Context.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
```

It will return an instance of `IHttpConnectionFeature` with the following properties:

```
public interface IHttpConnectionFeature
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The unique identifier for the connection the request was received on. This is
    //     primarily for diagnostic purposes.
    string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The IPAddress of the client making the request. Note this may be for a proxy
    //     rather than the end user.
    IPAddress? RemoteIpAddress { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The local IPAddress on which the request was received.
    IPAddress? LocalIpAddress { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The remote port of the client making the request.
    int RemotePort { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The local port on which the request was received.
    int LocalPort { get; set; }
}
```

Code example:

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
     var feature = Context.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
     _logger.LogInformation("Client connected with IP {RemoteIpAddress}", feature.RemoteIpAddress);
     return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Exactly what I was looking for  :)